# Spring configuration file cannot parse elements defined in my own schema

Tags: .net, xsd, spring.net

I have a very simple xsd which defines an element "cache"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://mysite/schema/cache"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://mysite/schema/cache">

    <xsd:complexType name="objectType" abstract="false">
        <xsd:attribute name="target" type="xsd:string">
        </xsd:attribute>
     </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="cacheType">
       <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="object" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
       </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="cache" type="cacheType"></xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have a spring config file with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
     xmlns:cache="http://mysite/schema/cache"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://mysite/schema/cache http://mysite/cache.xsd">

   <description>
   </description>

  <cache:cache>
    <cache:object target="site"/>
 </cache:cache>
</objects>
```

During the call to

```
Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectDefinitionReader.DoLoadObjectDefinitions at startup, I get the following error:
    [XmlSchemaValidationException: The 'http://mysite/schema/cache:cache' element is not declared.]
```

This suggests that spring cant find my schema, but the xsd is available.

Any ideas why this isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare to Spring that your schema exists, See the [appendix on schema authoring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/extensible-xml.html)

Specifically section B.5. Registering the handler and the schema.

Spring uses two files to deal with schema discovery.

META-INF/spring.handlers contains a mapping of XML Schema URIs to namespace handler classes.

META-INF/spring.schemas contains a mapping of XML Schema locations (referred to along with the schema declaration in XML files that use the schema as part of the 'xsi:schemaLocation' attribute) to classpath resources.

Comment: Well, I defined a Namespace parser and that works now.. apart from the fact my schema seems to be arse

Comment: My xsd didnt have the attribute elementFormDefault="qualified"!

Comment: For details of the elementFormDefault usage, see this discussion: http://www.xfront.com/HideVersusExpose.html

Comment: It does indeed - I'm now attempting to register a postprocessor within a subclass of AbstractSimpleObjectDefinitionParser :)